# Google Analytics - New or existing View for website relaunch

Tags: google-analytics

I am relaunching my current website and I want it to be easy to measure and compare the performance before and after the relaunch. Can I use the existing View for the new website and annotate the relaunch date or is it better to create a new View? And if I create a new View, how can I compare the two Views?

Comment: If you want to compare you need to use the same view.   GA doesn't have any way of comparing different views that I know of.

Answer (score 1):

I would keep the old View and add an annotation as you have mentioned.

I would also create a new View with an include hostname filter for the domain name and an exclude IP filter for your own IP.